# How to delay curl request

Tags: linux, bash, curl, terminal

I'd like to add sleep to this request so as not to stress the server with too many requests at a go. I've tried adding sleep but I don't get the expected behaviour. The help is appreciated.

```
xargs -I{} curl --location --request POST 'https://g.com' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer cc' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "c_ids": [
        "{}"
    ]
}' '; sleep 5m' < ~/recent.txt
```

Comment: it would make sense to use a shell loop instead of `xargs` if you want to add a delay. Also, `sleep 5m` waits 5 minutes, is that what you want?

Comment: What does your input look like? If it isn't already escaped as JSON, you should probably use `jq` to replace tabs with `\t`, quotes with `\"`, and otherwise make sure the string is legal to be substituted into JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping arbitrary strings into valid JSON is a job for [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

If you don't have a particular reason to define the curl args outside your loop:

```
while IFS= read -r json; do
  curl \
    --location --request POST 'https://g.com' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer cc' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "$json"
  sleep 5m
done < <(jq -Rc '{"c_ids": [ . ]}' recent.txt)
```

...or if you do:

```
curl_args=(
  --location --request POST 'https://g.com' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer cc' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
)

while IFS= read -r json; do
  curl "${curl_args[@]}" --data-raw "$json"
  sleep 5m
done < <(jq -Rc '{"c_ids": [ . ]}' recent.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to bash FAQ. There’s a wealth of knowledge there

Answer (score 0):

Putting the sleep in the xargs is a bit wonky.  I advise the following approach which is more likely to supply the desired result.

```
#!/bin/sh

siteCommon="--location --request POST 'https://g.com' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer cc' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' "

while read -r line
do
    eval curl ${siteCommon} --data-raw \'{ \"c_ids\": [ \"${line}\" ] }\'
    sleep 5m
done < ~/recent.txt
```

Comment: This hits the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Quotes aren't honored during string expansion, so `${siteCommon}` passes `--header` as one argument, `'Authorization` as another, `Bearer` as another, `cc'` as a fourth, etc.

Comment: `eval` hits separate issues -- read BashFAQ #48.

Comment: ...the safe way to fix this is to use an array, as #50 describes. (I was about to add a competing answer doing just that, but if you have it covered, no need).

Comment: (also, use the `-r` argument to `read` so backslashes in the input don't get eaten before they make it into `line`; as it is this would never work with a string that contains `\n`, `\t`, or similar; it also has other problems with strings that need to be escaped before they're valid in JSON, like ones that contain literal quotes).

Comment: @Charles, I don't use arrays (no experience there).  I will leave it to you to submit the answer with that approach.

Comment: Done. BTW, it's not all that unsafe for your current use case, but as a general good practice I suggest `eval "curl ${siteCommon} --data-raw '{ \"c_ids\": [ \"${line}\" ] }'"`, making it explicit that `eval` takes a single string as input. (If you pass `eval` multiple strings it combines them into one by adding whitespace between them before starting parsing, but this often has nonintuitive side effects)

Comment: @Charles, thanks for that hint.  I will remember that.

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/HotVacantMysql#main.sh for an online repl example showing how that can bite you (taking an input line of `more * funky * "example"` and passing curl the data `{ "c_ids": [ "more main.sh replit.nix funky main.sh replit.nix "example"" ] }`, with filenames substituted in place of the `*`s.

Comment: (there's also, of course, security risk if `line` contains, say, `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` -- the literal quotes inside the variable cancel out the ones added with the `\'` sequences; the way to protect against that is to make `${line}` instead be `\${line}` so it's expanded after `eval` is invoked instead of before; that's not a bug that passing eval only a single argument will avoid).

Comment: @Charles, while I understand the justification for that level of paranoia, I am glad that I no longer do coding for corporate servers. :-)

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer to add that extra backslash before the `$` in `${line}`?

Comment: @Charles, that $ must *not* be escaped.  Otherwise, the value will not be incorporated the way it needs to be.  Need to protect the literal value of the string within the quotes.

Comment: I meant what I said: It's only the `$` in `$siteCommon` that cannot be escaped, because that's the one where the value needs to be expanded before `eval`'s extra parsing pass; for the one in `$line` you want the expansion to happen _after_ `eval` is invoked; escaping prevents that expansion from happening earlier.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're doing -- the single quotes suppressing expansion later. That's dangerous: it creates the circumstance where `'$(rm -rf ~)'` runs. You want to expand as much as you can as _late_ as you possibly can.

Comment: A safe version of that line would like `eval "echo curl ${siteCommon} --data-raw '{ \"c_ids\": [ \"'\"\${line}\"'\" ] }'"` -- that way `${line}` is still unexpanded when `eval` starts, so nothing it contains can possibly be parsed as code, even if the value contains literal single quotes.

Comment: That's a brain twister!  I will have to study that long and hard to fathom what the Jedi Master is trying to explain to the padawan.